# MSChart, show Y value on Axe-Y2 when mouse move

Tags: c#, mschart

I use this code to show data values on chart (tooltip) when mouse move and it works fine.

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  string info = "Value: " + "#VAL{N2}" + "\n" + "Average: " + "#AVG{N2}" + "\n" + "Plus Bas: " + "#MIN{N2}" + "\n" + "Plus Haut: " + "#MAX{N2}" + "\n" +
    "First: " + "#FIRST{N2}" + "\n" + "Last: " + "#LAST{N2}";

  chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "Series name..." + "\n" + info;
  chart1.Series[1].ToolTip = "Series name2..." + "\n" + info;
  chart1.Series[2].ToolTip = "Series name3..." + "\n" + info;

  System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);

  chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0;
  chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);
  chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);

}
```

But i would like to see the current Y value (#VALY) on the axe-Y2 moving during the moving like this (the red circle is the place i would like to show the value)
[Desired position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S12G4.png)

Can you help me please...

Comment: You could add a TextAnotation at the x-position of the x2-axis, change its y-value and text accordingly..

Comment: I had the same problem and found the solution. [See my post/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152436/mschart-c-get-the-high-low-barchart-candlestick-chart-value-chart-coordonat)