# MSChart, C#, Get the High/Low (barchart/candlestick chart) value chart coordonate (X,Y) in pixel by code

Tags: c#, mschart

I would like to retrieve the X, Y coordinates for the High and Low values of a bar chart or candle by code and not the values of the points represented on the chart.
Can you help me please
thank you

Comment: use one or more of the various axis conversion functions to do that. [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.valuetopixelposition?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the `ValueToPixelPosition` track. I searched and found [this perfectly functional solution](https://www.it-swarm-fr.com/fr/c%23/voir-les-valeurs-des-points-du-graphique-lorsque-la-souris-est-sur-des-points/1066872304/).

By specifying

```
dataPoint.YValues [0]
```

With options:

- `0` = High
- `1` = Low
- `2` = Open
- `3` = Close